# how to add text area on canvas using jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a textarea and canvas. The user is able to drag image onto the canvas and change different background images. Now I need to be able to have a section at the bottom of canvas that will display text from textarea.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="280"></canvas>

    <div id="text">
        <textarea id="write_whatever">Write 4 lines to describe yourself.</textarea>
        <div id="button_to_add"></div>
    </div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle of what i currently have http://jsfiddle.net/D4zw4/50/

Here's what I am trying to achieve, but instead of key up it's with button click and it should be at the bottom of the canvas http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NuaHp/

Anyone know how I could achieve this or done this before? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('#button_to_add').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var text = $('#write_whatever').val();

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#3e3e3e";
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(text, 20, canvas.height - 20);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4zw4/51/

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, is it possible for it to display the text that is in the textarea onload?

Comment: Sure, at the end of your document.ready function trigger the click event.